# Why can't I reuse c = getchar(); on str2 after using it on str1? (C)

Tags: c, string, char, character, getchar

I am doing exercise 2-4 in K&R C wherein I am to make an alternative of `squeeze(s1,s2)` that deletes each character from `s2` that occurs in `s1`.

I am going to show you how I made this part from the top and why so I ask for your patience... (This is the version when the error occurred)

First, I declared 2 variables `str1[LIMIT]` and `str2[LIMIT]` where `LIMIT` has the value to hold `1024` characters like so:

```
char str1[LIMIT], str2[LIMIT];
```

Second, I defined variables `c`, `i`, `j`, and `lim` where `c` will be concatenated to `str1` and `str2`; `i` will be used iterate for `str1` and `j` is for `str2`.

```
int c, i, j, lim;
```

Third, I proceed to concatenate each character found in `c` to `str1`.

```
/* concatenate each character in c to str1 */
    lim = LIMIT;
    while (lim > 0) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n') {
            lim = 0;
        }
        else {
            str1[i] = c;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    str1[i] = '\0';
```

This worked, I can prove that by printing the value of `str1`:

```
Create string...
Create string...
```

It read my input and printed it as expected but when I reused `c = getchar()` on `str2` like so:

```
/* concatenate each character in c to str2 */
lim = LIMIT;
while (lim > 0) {
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF ||  c == '\n') {
        lim = 0;
    }
    else {
        str2[j] = c;
        ++j;
    }
}
str2[j] = '\0';
```

I reused `c = getchar();` because I thought since all characters in `c = getchar();` are already in `str1`, why not re-assign `c = getchar();` and put all the characters in `str2`?

I did that and I kept getting asked for more inputs than what I should be asked...

```
Create string...
Delete string...
...
```

The `...` meant that it kept asking me for inputs.

I declared a variable called `d` which will be `d = getchar();` and changed the code for concatenating to `str2` like so:

```
/* concatenate each character in d to str2 */
lim = LIMIT;
while (lim > 0) {
    d = getchar();
    if (d == EOF ||  d == '\n') {
        lim = 0;
    }
    else {
        str2[j] = d;
        ++j;
    }
}
str2[j] = '\0';
```

I then ran the program successfully like so:

```
Create string...
Delete string...
Create string...
Delete string...
```

At first the program read the inputs `Create string...` and `Delete string...` then printed them.

**But why can't I reuse `c = getchar();` on `str2` like I did on `str1`? Isn't doing that re-assigns the characters for `str2`?**

[Here](https://gist.github.com/alexanderfalgui/3d74a5cf778a79c74ec4)'s the full code.

Comment: In your "str2 with c" `if (c == EOF ||  d == '\n')` I see a `d`. Is that a typo in your code or only here ?

Comment: Oops, that's a typo. Sorry about that. I experimented with `c` and `d` but I completely forgot about changing that. That's fixed now.

Comment: Can you show a full program that demonstrates the problem please?  There are many potential problems in the code you show (`i`, `j` being uninitialised for instance).  I suspect many of these are just typos in the question (as with the problem Leiaz spotted) but there's no way to know for sure without a fuller statement of your problem.

Comment: The link of the full code is posted but I request you look into it after 5 minutes since there's a lot of things that will confuse you which I am fixing them.

Comment: You guys can look now: https://gist.github.com/alexanderfalgui/3d74a5cf778a79c74ec4                  It has two versions: One is when the error occurred and the other is what I did to solve the problem.

Comment: You can reuse the c. Your code works here (except if you input more than 1023 characters, because you aren't checking if you are at the LIMIT !), but it doesn't contain the part that prints the strings. Do you still get the same problem with the code you posted ? Were you trying to end input with `EOF` (on Linux with xterm, Ctrl+D twice) ?

Comment: @Leiaz, will you please post an answer on how I can reuse `c` for two strings `str1` and `str2` by asking me two inputs and storing them respectively if you can?

Comment: The way you have done it should work. You don't need to do anything special to use `c` for the second string.

Comment: I guess it's a typo. Thanks a lot @Leiaz. I need to pay more attention to my code...

Comment: Just as additional evidence in support of what Leiaz said, your code works fine for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
c = getchar();
```

retrieves a single character (as an int type) from stdin (ie: the keyboard) and stores that value in `c`.  Hence, each time this line is executed, it will generally wait for the user to input a character.

It appears that the question code is attempting to obtain two strings. To put it bluntly, the question code can use `c` in both loops.  Something else is apparently wrong.

NOTE:*There is no affiliation between `c` and `str1` or `str2` beyond the following statement, which copies the single character from `c` to the str1 (or str2) array:*

```
str2[j] = c;
```

Remove the getchar() calls completely from the code, and simply initialize the two strngs with test values:

```
char str1[] = "Alexander B. Falgui";
char str2[] = ".B";
```

Pass these strings into your `squeeze()` function and verify that the result is what was expected.

---

See spoiler code **[here](http://www.mahonri.info/SO/23878448_why-cant-i-reuse-c-getchar-on-str2-after-using-it-on-str1-c.c)**.

Comment: It seems that your answer changes from time to time... I'll take a look at that again after 10 minutes. But it seems that I can't seem to find the answer I am looking for in your answer, I think I'll keep re-reading it.

Comment: @AlexanderB.Falgui, Perhaps the 'spoiler' link I just added to the end will help?

Comment: Nope the 'spoiler link' didn't help. I never asked for the solution of this exercise, I asked why I can't assign `c = getchar();` for `str2` like I did for `str1`. I wanted to declare as less variables as possible.